# How do I specify that a specific Azure job needs a given OS on the level of the jobs?

Tags: azure-devops

All of my build agents are in one pool but different build agents have a different OS. Certain jobs however need Windows and I at the moment unsuccessfully try to tell that to azure via demands:

```
stages:
  - stage: project_frontend
    dependsOn: common_container
    demands: Agent.OS -equals Windows_NT
    jobs:
      - job: build_container
        steps:
          - task: Docker@2
            displayName: 'login to docker hub'
            inputs:
              command: login
              containerRegistry: dockerHubServiceConnection
```

Comment: You should add `pool: your-pool` under the `- stage: ....` before the `demands: ....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check documentation here: [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema). The [job](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#job) level supports [pool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops&tabs=schema#pool) and [demands](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/demands?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml). As [example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/phases?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#dependencies) for the Microsoft hosted agents:

```
jobs:
- job: Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from Windows
- job: macOS
  pool:
    vmImage: 'macOS-10.14'
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from macOS
- job: Linux
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  steps:
  - script: echo hello from Linux
```